ER диаграмма sql
Делаю ER-диаграмму. Я хотел спросить, есть ли у меня ошибки, что можно поменять, убрать или изменить, а также что можно добавить. вот ссылка на диаграмму- скриншот взят отсюда


А где ПОЛНОЕ И ПОДРОБНОЕ описание предметной области и выполненного вами анализа?
